# Insert just the date to MS access database using FireDac

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-10-seattle, firedac

I have a table called `Students` , in this table there is a `date` column called `BirthDay` with `Date, abbreviated` format (eg : 26/06/2017), the problem is in delphi the `Field` type is `SQLTimeStamp`, and I want to save just the `Date` not a `DateTime`.

```
DM.TStudentsBirthDay.Value := DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp(DateTimePicker1.Date);
```

That will post a `DateTime`.

How can I fix this? How can I insert just the date?

Update :

I try to do it with `TFDQuery` component and it works perfectly , also with `TAODTable` component.

Comment: What is `TStudentsBirthDay`? Which FireDAC component do you use? Do you use LiveBindings?

Comment: `TStudents` is FireDac table , `BirthDay` is the field , I'm using `TFDTable` component , and no I'm not using  LiveBindings.

Comment: Thanks for the info, though my question might have been pointless. I'm afraid, FireDAC is correct here, the DATE data type is in ODBC mapped to [SQL_TIMESTAMP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types).

Comment: @Victoria Alright , So I can't insert just the date with firedac components? is that what you try to say?

Comment: Try to define the field definition as be `TDateField` then.

Comment: That w'll not work

Comment: You are right, sorry. So long the table is populated by MS Access schema, it will be `SQL_TIMESTAMP` data type. Of course with `TFDQuery` you can access parameters by specific types where can FireDAC cut off proper portion (or use macros), but doesn't change anything on internal storage of MS Access of such value (I guess it's so because I haven't found separate data types). I would leave your question on someone else.

Comment: As far as I know, Access always stores date/time fields as date + time. It just doesn't display the time part if it's set to 00:00:00 and the time part isn't explicitly displayed. As long as you adjust your code to set the time portion to that, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Use `DM.TStudentsBirthDay.Value := DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp(DateOf(DateTimePicker1.Date));` to remove time potion from the date time picker, or simply set the date time in the picker to midnight. see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.DateUtils.DateOf

Comment: @Erik, thanks for confirming single data type for date/time values. But adding e.g. 12 hours to 26/06/2017 23:00:00 and 26/06/2017 06:00:00 and working with the resulting date portion later makes a difference. So, it can make sense to reset the time portion to midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @Gerry Coll for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757039/insert-just-the-date-to-ms-access-database-using-firedac?noredirect=1#comment76499340_44757039).

Using [`DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.SqlTimSt.DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp) and [`DateOf()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.DateUtils.DateOf) functions:

```
DM.TStudentsBirthDay.Value := DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp(DateOf(DateTimePicker1.Date));
```

That works perfectly.